# git format-patch for new sub-directories

Tags: git

I tried to find a way to generate a patch file from a git repo by extracting changed files/directories, which can be used to apply to a master branch stored on another computer without network access.

I followed a [blog](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/) here about creating and applying a patch with git found through Google. So I followed the blog, and tried to transfer some changes I made, including the addition of a new sub-folder, some new and modified files.

The steps I tried based on the above blog are basically:

```
#Creating the patch on the changed branch
git format-patch master --stdout > fix_something.patch

#Applying the patch
git apply --check fix_something.patch
git am --signoff < fix_something.patch
```

In the end, `git apply --check` does not return any error and the new and modified files were successfully transferred. But the new sub-folder was empty in the target project. None of the content was transferred.

Am I missing something in this process?

(By the way, the added sub-folder was a copy of another (independent) git project. I know about sub-modules, but didn't want to bother as my target computer has no internet access.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to find a way to generate a patch file from a git repo ... to apply to a master branch stored on another computer without network access.

The best approach to achieve what you want is to use [**`git bundle`**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)

Regarding your second part of the question:

> By the way, the added sub-folder was a copy of another git project ... `submodule` ...
>   But the new sub-folder was empty in the target project

Since the folder is a `submodule` there will be no file inside as this is an "external" repository as far as git handle it. You will have to apply the same solution for the root repo and for the `submodule`.

From your question i assume that you know what `submodule` is. If not look at it as repository inside repository. Git manage those as separate repositories so the content of the `submodule` is not managed by the root repo.

Comment: Thanks.  The added folder was an independent git project with many files. Sorry about the confusion. I edited the question to clarify on this.